# Download file from google cloud storage directly to client in nodejs

Tags: node.js, download, google-cloud-storage

I want to be able to send the file downloaded from google cloud directly to the client and not have to first save on my server then create a download to client from the saved version on my server, cause this make the process slow, as the file is downloaded two times, first from google cloud to my own server then from my own server to client.

```
router.get("/:filename", async(req, res) => {
  try {
    // Grab filename from request parameter
    const fetchURL =req.params.filename;
    const file = await File.findOne({fetchURL});
    const srcFileName = file.originalname;
  // Call GCS with bucketName and check the file method with srcFileName and check again with download method which takes download path as argument
    storage
      .bucket(bucketName)
      .file(srcFileName)
      .download({
        destination: path.join(process.cwd(), "downloads", srcFileName)
      })
      .then(() =>
        res.download(path.join(process.cwd(), "downloads", srcFileName), err =>
          err ? console.log(err) : null
        )
      )
      .catch(err =>res.status(400).json({
        message: err.message
      }));
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(res.statusCode).json({
      message: `There was an error downloading your file. ${err.message}`
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: If you do not like to download the file in your server before serving it to the public, an alternative would be to use [Signed URLs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls) which can give a time-limited resource access to anyone regardless of whether they have a Google Account. [Here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signing-urls-with-helpers#storage-signed-url-object-nodejs) you would also find how to easily generate those signed URLs and pass them to the user, in your case the client without downloading the file into your server. I hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you  @ChristopherRodriguezConde you are very right,  I did found that out in the documentation as I couldn't get any responses after hours so what I did was generate signed URL valid for 10 minutes and send to the client.

Comment: My org policy bans publicly accessible urls. There must be a way to get the file's contents in program directly?

Answer (score 7):

This works for me in NodeJS+Express server:

```
const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage');
const storage = new Storage({projectId, keyFilename}); 

router.get('/:id', async function (req, res) {

   let fileName = 'test.jpg'; //For example
   let contetType = 'image/jpg;' //For example
   res.writeHead(200, {
    'Content-Disposition': `attachment;filename=${filename}`,
    'Content-Type': `${contetType}`
   });

   await storage
   .bucket('my-bucket')
   .file(`Images/${req.params.id}/${filename}`)
   .createReadStream() //stream is created
   .pipe(res);
   });}
```

Comment: Could you upload the full version of your code, as I see it now, it is only part of it? Or this is what it is ?

Comment: This is the entire code of the get api. Everything else is just node + express.